# Cant Ping to my computer

Tags: networking, ping

There are three computers like Computer A, Computer B and Computer C all are in same network:

1. Computer A can't ping Computer B and Computer C.
2. Computer B and Computer C can't ping Computer A.
3. Computer B and Computer C can ping with each other.

Following things I tried:

1. Enable and disable firewall.
2. Add custom rule like ICMPv4 for allowing echo request in windows firewall inbound rule.
3. Uninstall the Antivirus.
4. Computer A can ping `google.com`.

**Main Aim** Computer A should be ping to another computer and ping by other computer.

I am stucked. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get a good answer, try specifying your operating systems. Are you pinging by name or IP address? Does "the same network" mean they are plugged into the same switch, getting ip from the same dhcp server? Can they all access the internet? Without these data, you are asking a fairly vague question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft Windows Please follow these steps:

1. Go to Network
2. at the top menu click Network and Sharing Center
3. Left side click on Chjange advanced sharing settings
4. You would see two to options Home or Work & Public

Click both of them in Network discovery Please turn on network discovery